# A way to simplify these if statements

Tags: logic

I've often run into this situation where I have a complicated if statement with a lot of inner if statements and a lot of repeated code. It essentially boils down to I have a bunch of cases and certain code blocks that execute based on those statements, but if a different condition is true then I want those code blocks to execute in different conditions. Here's a generic example:

```
if (condition) {
    if (conditionA) {
        codeBlockW;
    }
    else if (conditionB) {
        codeBlockX;
    }
    else if (conditionC) {
        codeBlockY;
    }
    else if (conditionD) {
        codeBlockZ;
    }
}
else {
    if (conditionA) {
        codeBlockZ;
    }
    else if (conditionB) {
        codeBlockY;
    }
    else if (conditionC) {
        codeBlockX;
    }
    else if (conditionD) {
        codeBlockW;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((condition AND conditionA) OR (!condition AND conditionD)) { codeBlockW }
else if ((condition AND conditionB) OR (!condition AND conditionC)) { codeBlockX }
else if ((condition AND conditionC) OR (!condition AND conditionB)) { codeBlockY }
else if ((condition AND conditionD) OR (!condition AND conditionA)) { codeBlockZ }
```

You can shorten it a little bit like this maybe, I don't imagine any shorter way...